# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.12.77:443: i/o timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubectl, amazon-eks

Iam trying to set up aws cluster. I installed kubectl and configured aws with credentials. When I tried to display pods or any kubectl commands, Iam getting this error

```
revaa@revaa-Lenovo-E41-25:~$ kubectl get pod
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.0.12.77:443: i/o timeout
```

How to resolve this

Comment: `10.0.12.77` is a private address, not accessible from outside of AWS without a VPN. Is your cluster private?

Answer (score 5):

The ip used is a private, it cannot be accessed outside the aws. Change your cluster's api server endpoint access to public. It worked.

Comment: More details here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-endpoint.html